# Is it harmful for SEO to repeat the same call to action at the bottom of every page?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, technical-seo

My website consists of 4 pages. These pages explain what programming languages are.

On all the pages above, there are articles and images about why you should get software service from me after the content is finished. These images and texts are available on all programming language pages.

The content you need to get software service is at the end of 4 pages. Does this count as duplicate content? And will it cause SEO problems?

In addition, the content you need to get software service consists of 300 words. So it's really some content, but it's on every page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google accounts for these sort of "boilerplate" content blocks.

In this case you're talking about like a *Call to Action statement*.

You're totally fine, it's not going to hurt you. These are very normal sections for pages to contain after the primary body content is finished.

---

### What *would* be duplicate content?

If you copy and pasted content from another website and sort of reworded it a little, and tried to claim that *your* page as the canonical - that would be dinged as duplicate content.

Sometimes it makes a lot of sense to duplicate certain content from your site, like reviews, across pages. 3rd party content such as passages from Wikipedia pages get duplicated all of the time - the reason it's *not* duplicate content is because it's *supplementing* the primary content.

A great example is like on this site - we duplicate content all the time from other sites in answers when referencing documentation, guidelines, or passages that *corroborate* claims. But it's not like it makes up our *whole answer*.

When Google seriously penalizes sites for duplicate content, it's typically because the site is overtly trying to *cheat*. Like plagiarism.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine what each page would look like if you removed the 300-word advert, and if that hypothetical page would still be unique, fleshed out, and stand on its own as useful content, then I would not worry about your pages being downranked as duplicate.

Also note that duplicate content does not count towards any penalties, unless it is blatantly excessive or spammy enough to spill over into real issues like the ["Thin Content" penalty](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175?hl=en#zippy=%2Cthin-content-with-little-or-no-added-value), which is definitely not the case here.